# How to remove service messages from Telegram with Bot API?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I have a supergroup in Telegram and a Bot, which is administrator of a group. When a new user join or left group, service message (with grey background) is appear in chat, for example

```
Username join to a chat
Username is join to a chat by invite link
Username is left the chat
```

Is it possible to catch and delete such service messages from chat with Bot API? Thanks in advance!

PS. I'am using https://github.com/php-telegram-bot/core

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `Request::sendMessage()` to [each update events](https://github.com/php-telegram-bot/core#predefined-commands)

PS. There already have [@AntiServiceMessageBot](https://t.me/AntiServiceMessageBot) can do this.

Comment: Thank you for answear! I'am already make a decision with php-telegram-bot commands Newchatmembers and Leftchatmember.